# How to install WSUS offline update `.cab` and `.msu` files (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, wsus

I have a 21H2 Windows machine with no internet access that I need to install Windows updates on. I used [WSUS community edition](https://gitlab.com/wsusoffline/wsusoffline/-/releases) to download the updates, and now I have a folder with a bunch of `.cab` and `.msu` files in them:

[image]
[image]

I can move these over to the offline machine now, but I'm not sure what the proper way to install them is. Do I have to double click on each `.cab` and `.msu` file individually? Or do I just run the three `.msu` files in the `19041` folder? Or is there some way to install these using a batch or powershell script? I don't know the correct way to install all of these.

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry, to clarify, it's only the .msu files that need to be run and not the .cab files?

Comment: You need to install everything.

Comment: My apologies I thought you had used something else to download the updates, InstallOSUpdate.cmd, should be the only thing you need to run.

Answer (score 0):

I really really advise against using this scheme, because you would be
installing updates in a random order.

Updates have an order : For example, if update B corrects update A,
but you install B before A, then you will be creating a non-viable
version of Windows.

I would instead advise to download a complete version of Windows as ISO,
and to install it via the
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Remember that an installation can always go wrong, so good backups
are required (although the chances of success are excellent).

Comment: I have used WSUS Offline for years. I never had a problem with installing updates in the correct order. Creating an ISO for each cumulative update seems like an overkill solution to a very simple problem solved by WSUS Offline.

Comment: @Ramhound: How would WSUS Offline treat the poster's mass of msu & cab files? Never used it, so I'm curious.

Comment: It would attempt to install the updates, updates that are superseded would either be installed, then replaced after a reboot. The process would continue until the update are installed. I have in the years using Offline WSUS to update an offline install of Windows 7 never once had a problem. Would expect Windows 10 to be even easier.

Comment: @Ramhound: How does it know that msu1 supersedes msu2? Or does it download all the updates at once into a sort of database?

Comment: @Ramhound: Perhaps it would be better if you posted an answer that explained all this. I'm interested.

Comment: All the author has to do is run `InstallOSUpdate.cmd` and it will install every applicable update they downloaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142443/discussion-between-ramhound-and-harrymc).